# Opensearch Scripted Fields on an Rollup Index

Tags: opensearch

Say I have an index which is produced by a roll up job. Can I create scripted fields on that index in an index pattern?

I'm getting the error:

```
search_phase_execution_exception: [illegal_argument_exception] Reason: Roolup search must have size explicitly set to 0, but found 10
```